# Converting JSON Object to Flat Structure using Logic Apps

Tags: json, google-analytics, azure-logic-apps

So I have been using this logic apps template to hit the Google Analytics API and the response is in this format

```
{
  "reports": [
    {
      "columnHeader": {
        "dimensions": [
          "ga:date",
          "ga:campaign",
          "ga:country",
          "ga:browser",
          "ga:deviceCategory",
          "ga:sourceMedium",
          "ga:socialNetwork",
          "ga:region"
        ],
        "metricHeader": {
          "metricHeaderEntries": [
            {
              "name": "ga:users",
              "type": "INTEGER"
            },
            {
              "name": "ga:sessions",
              "type": "INTEGER"
            },
            {
              "name": "ga:newUsers",
              "type": "INTEGER"
            },
            {
              "name": "ga:bounces",
              "type": "INTEGER"
            },
            {
              "name": "ga:pageviews",
              "type": "INTEGER"
            },
            {
              "name": "ga:sessionDuration",
              "type": "TIME"
            },
            {
              "name": "ga:hits",
              "type": "INTEGER"
            },
            {
              "name": "ga:goalCompletionsAll",
              "type": "INTEGER"
            },
            {
              "name": "ga:goalConversionRateAll",
              "type": "PERCENT"
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "data": {
        "rows": [
          {
            "dimensions": [
              "20200312",
              "(not set)",
              "India",
              "Chrome",
              "desktop",
              "(direct) / (none)",
              "(not set)",
              "Tamil Nadu"
            ],
            "metrics": [
              {
                "values": [
                  "4",
                  "4",
                  "4",
                  "0",
                  "111",
                  "5100.0",
                  "111",
                  "0",
                  "0.0"
                ]
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "dimensions": [
              "20200316",
              "(not set)",
              "India",
              "Chrome",
              "desktop",
              "(direct) / (none)",
              "(not set)",
              "Tamil Nadu"
            ],
            "metrics": [
              {
                "values": [
                  "1",
                  "1",
                  "0",
                  "0",
                  "6",
                  "266.0",
                  "6",
                  "0",
                  "0.0"
                ]
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "dimensions": [
              "20200318",
              "(not set)",
              "India",
              "Chrome",
              "desktop",
              "(direct) / (none)",
              "(not set)",
              "Tamil Nadu"
            ],
            "metrics": [
              {
                "values": [
                  "1",
                  "2",
                  "0",
                  "0",
                  "20",
                  "135.0",
                  "20",
                  "0",
                  "0.0"
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        ],
        "totals": [
          {
            "values": [
              "6",
              "7",
              "4",
              "0",
              "137",
              "5501.0",
              "137",
              "0",
              "0.0"
            ]
          }
        ],
        "rowCount": 3,
        "minimums": [
          {
            "values": [
              "1",
              "1",
              "0",
              "0",
              "6",
              "135.0",
              "6",
              "0",
              "0.0"
            ]
          }
        ],
        "maximums": [
          {
            "values": [
              "4",
              "4",
              "4",
              "0",
              "111",
              "5100.0",
              "111",
              "0",
              "0.0"
            ]
          }
        ],
        "isDataGolden": true
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I Want to convert it and bring it in a form that the column header:dimensions and metric header entries name will become column names and their values,ie data.rows.dimensions and metrics.values become corresponding values

```
ga:date ga:campaign ga:country  ga:browser  ga:deviceCategory   ga:sourceMedium ga:socialNetwork    ga:region   ga:users    ga:sessions ga:newUsers : (column names)
20200316    (not set)   India   Chrome  desktop (direct) / (none)   (not set)   Tamil Nadu  1   1   1 :(values)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can use an Integration account, I suggest to create a flat file schema with the desired structure, and in the logic app you can convert in xml and then apply the Flat File Encoding.

Otherwise a function app should resolve your issue